# What is the difference between both of these class statements?

Tags: c++, class, vector, properties

I am sorry if the title of my question is too vague, but I do not know how to easily describe what I am trying to figure out. Essentially I have a class that has a property of type std::vector, which is supposed to contain pointers to itself. I tried building and running both of the supplied codes, and I got no errors, so now I am wondering what is the difference between both of these codes?
code 1:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<MyClass *> Container;
};
```

code 2:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<MyClass> * Container;
};
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: First is a vector of pointers to `MyClass`. Second is a pointer to vector of instances of `MyClass`.

Comment: `std::vector<MyClass *> Container;` This is a vector that contains a list of pointers to `MyClass` elements... `std::vector<MyClass> * Container;` This is a pointer to a vector that contains `MyClass` elements.

Comment: @mike bayko  How many pointers to itself can an object  have in the vector? Maybe you mean a static data member of the type std::vector?

Comment: If you take your test [a little bit further](http://ideone.com/Ri0EjK), you can see which class fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you are defining an array of MyClass pointers.

Case 1:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<MyClass *> Container;
};
```

In this case, the sizeof(Container) will be sizeof(MyClass*) (size of pointer) X length of vector. Same as the vector itself.
You would access the variable like this...

```
// ChildContainer is a vector
ChildContainer = myInstance->Container[i]->Container;
```

In the second case, you are defining a pointer to an array of class instances (which are themselves also pointers already, anyway). Here, the sizeof(Container) will be the size of a pointer. The vector itself will be sizeof(MyClass) (the instance pointer!) X length of vector.

Case 2:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<MyClass> * Container;
};
```

You would access the variable like this...

```
// ChildContainer is a pointer to a vector
ChildContainer = myInstance->(*Container)[i]->Container;
```

If MyClass were actually a struct, accessing could be a little different because structs are not pointers by default.

Case 1:

```
struct MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<MyClass*> Container;
};
```

Use:

```
// ChildContainer is a vector
ChildContainer = myInstance.Container[i]->Container;
```

Case 2:

```
struct MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<MyClass> * Container;
};
```

Use:

```
// ChildContainer is a pointer to a vector
ChildContainer = myInstance.(*Container)[i].Container;
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: @juanchopanza explain. Just saying it's wrong is not very helpful.

Comment: I have NO idea what you are talking about and I don't care enough to try and guess nor waste anymore time on what amounts to semantics anyway. The sizeof stuff was purely to illustrate the difference in the declarations. You can fix it up if you want.